# Recursive Linked List. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
public class Reverse {

  public static void printLL(Node head) {
      while(head!=null){
          System.out.print(head.getData()+"-->");
          head=head.next;
      }
  }

  public static Node reverseLL(Node head){
      if(head == null) {
          return head;
      }
      return reverseLL(head.next);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Node first=new Node(10);
      Node head=first;
      Node second=new Node(20);
      first.next=second;
      Node third=new Node(30);
      second.next=third;
      Node fourth=new Node(40);
      third.next=fourth;
      printLL(head);
      System.out.println("\nReverse of Linked List is \n");
      head=reverseLL(head);
      printLL(head);
   }
}
```

Here is my code. It is not printing anything.

I think that due to recursion, it is pointing to the null pointer and hence no data is present at null position.

Please tell me what can I do to make the code correct.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a stack trace?

Comment: I do not know about the stack trace.

Comment: How exactly is the method `reverseLL` supposed to reverse the linked list? From what I see - it always returns null. You have to actually construct a new linked list (given it's unidirectional) for it to work.

Comment: The first call to ``printLL`` should be printing something. The one after ``reverseLL`` cannot be working.

Answer (score 1):

Your `reverseLL` simply goes through all the Nodes and when it reaches the last one doing `if(head==null)`, `null` is returned.

You need to fix the `reverseLL` function. Try adding traces into the function to understand what it does step by step.

Answer (score 1):

You seemn to have missed a crucial point about recursion - you have to call yourself.

I will suggest a change to `printLL` that should demonstrate one possible recursive solution that should work.

```
public static void printLL(Node head) {

    if (head != null) {
        System.out.print(head.getData() + "-->");
        printLL(head.next);
    }
}
```

Note how the code basically says *if there is a head, print it's data and then print it's `head.next`*.

Comment: It works....can you please tell me how can I alter my code so that the reversed linked list is printed by the printLL(head) function?

Comment: @iVvaibhav - If you are learning recursion it does not help having someone do it for you. Examine the code I have poosted and work out what is happening for yourself, then modify your reverse process to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `reverseLL` does not do anything to the `head` after calling itself recursively.

The base case is right: when `head` is `null`, you return `null`. The recursive step, however, is not complete: you need to reverse the rest of the list, but then you have to attach it back to the `head`.

The simplest way to accomplish this is to pass an extra parameter for the `prior` node, so that you could do

```
head.next = prior;
```

inside your recursive method. Here is how your "wrapper" method would look:

```
public static Node reverseLL(Node head) {
    if(head==null){
        return null;
    }
    return reverseLL(head, null);
}
```

Note that it is not recursive - all it does is calling a two-argument overload.

The recursive method knows that `head` is never `null`, so its base case is `head.next == null`:

```
public static Node reverseLL(Node head, Node prior) {
    Node res;
    if (head.next == null) {
        res = head;
    } else {
        res = reverseLL(head.next, head);
    }
    head.next = prior;
    return res;
}
```

The reversal of the `head` node is done in the assignment prior to the `return`. Note how the method returns the last non-null node in the chain.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/OvhvUg)